# Getting org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector.. is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //*[contains(@id,'')]/x:td[7]/x:div[1] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.
```

I have a page in which I want to retrieve the text. The XPath I have entered is correctly retrieving the element when tested in XPath Checker. But when the test is run getting the above error.

I have written following code

```
List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'')]/x:td[7]/x:div[1]"));

for (WebElement we: list)
{
    System.out.println(we.getText());
}
```

I am testing on Firefox 24

Comment: What element does that XPath result in then?

Comment: Please include your input XML/HTML in your question.

Comment: <td height="70" valign="middle" width="70" style="border-bottom:1px solid #F2EFEF;border-left:0px solid #F2EFEF;border-top:1px solid #F2EFEF;">
                        <div style="font-weight:bold; text-indent:20px;">41 </div><br />
                        <div id="cache_pickupDetails" style="display:none"></div>
                    </td>

The XPATH I specified is of the area that should return the text i.e. number here it is 41, 32, 24